# Is there a continuous function $f$ satisfying the following Zygmund condition but not differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-equations, approximation-theory

Suppose that a continuous function $f$ on the line and satisfies
 $$
 |f(x+2h)−2f(x+h)+f(x)|\leq const \frac{|h|}{(\log\frac{1}{|h|})^{\beta}}\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{where}\,\,\,\, \beta \in(0, 1] 
 $$ 
 for all $x,h$ real.  Is it true that $f$ is differentiable? 
 If not how can I prove  it?

Comment: The Article "A Note on Smooth Functions" from Weiss and Zygmund is information about this class of functions at least in the periodic case. Maybe something can be generalized. http://goo.gl/ha7i4l

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Weierstrass-type function

$$ f(x) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n n^\beta} \sin(2^n x) $$

will obey the hypotheses, yet fails to be differentiable at the origin.

In general, one should look to Weierstrass-type functions (perhaps weighted by power weights $|x|^{-\alpha}$ or variants such as $|x|^{-\alpha} \log(\frac{1}{|x|})^{-\gamma}$, in case some $L^p$ norms are involved for a finite $p$) as key test cases for these sorts of endpoint functional embedding problems.  It is also quite clarifying to reformulate the hypotheses and conclusion in terms of Littlewood-Paley theory (either the classical theory using harmonic extensions, or the modern theory using smooth partitions of unity in frequency space; see e.g. Stein's "Singular integrals" for the former, or the appendix to my PDE book for the latter).  For instance, the hypothesis here is basically equivalent to the Besov-type bound

$$ \| P_N f \|_\infty \ll N^{-1} \log^{-\beta} N$$

for frequencies $N \gg 1$, where $P_N$ is a smooth Fourier projection to frequencies $|\xi| \sim N$, while the conclusion is roughly equivalent to the pointwise convergence of the series $\sum_N N P_N f(x)$ as $N$ ranges over dyadic integers.  As $\sum_N \log^{-\beta} N$ diverges for $\beta \leq 1$, this indicates that the claim is false, and then guided by this analysis one can quickly come up with the aforementioned Weierstrass-type counterexample.

Comment: Thank you very much Terry Tao. If we suppose  $f$ is absolutely continuous and satisfies above inequality, in this case, is it true that $f$ is differentiable and its derivative satisfies
$$
|f'(x)-f'(y)|\leq\frac{1}{(\log\frac{1}{|h|})^{\beta}}
$$Thanks

Comment: No, and one can see this by applying appropriate truncation to each of the terms in the previous example (note that absolute continuity is equivalent to the weak derivative of f being in L^1).  It would probably be a good exercise for you to work out the details.