# Differentiability criterion in the Zygmund class

Tags: real-analysis, differential-equations, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, approximation-theory

Let $ f: \mathbf{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbf{R} $ be a continuous
 function, $ \omega $ be a modulus of continuity and assume 
$$ | f(x+h) +f(x-h) -2f(x) | \leq \omega(|h|)|h| $$
whenever $ x,h \in \mathbf{R}^{m} $ and $ 0 \leq |h | \leq 1 $.

Is it known some sharp condition on $ \omega $ in order to have that $ f $ is continously differentiable?

Comment: Is $\omega$ a modulus of continuity of function $f$ itself? This looks somehow strange.

Comment: No, it is just a modulus of continuity for this second order difference quotient. If $ \omega $ is a generic modulus of continuity you get the class of smooth functions in the sense of Zygmund, that are known to be non differentiable a.e. in general.

Comment: If we do not require additionally that $f$ is continuous or something like that, it may appear that $f$ is additive discontinuous function.

Comment: you are right. f has to be assumed to be continuous. I added it.

Comment: related question https://mathoverflow.net/q/143659/6451